# Translating an Object to a certain Vector 3 in OpenGL and Java LWJGL

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

So after almost two hours, I got the hang of using glTranslated() (with Java and LWJGL). If I am correct, applying glTranslated on an object moves that object with the x,y,z relative to the previously moved object. I believe the correct term for this is local vs global, global being the one I want. I was wondering if there was a way to translate an object to a specific XYZ position, or relative to the origin. Thanks!

(Code or other details can be supplied if it helps, just let me know. Also sorry if this is a noob comment, Im very new to OpenGL.)

Comment: If this question makes no sense, it could be that I am going at this completely wrong and I made a logic error somewhere... If that's the case, please let me know. :)

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix-math and -multiplication? That is what is going on behind the scenes when you call glTranslate/glRotate etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's help. However, I found what I was looking for, and that was

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();
drawCube(x, y, z); //parameters for the glTranslated();
GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

Thanks again!

Comment: haha.. that's why you had to show some code for us to make sense. glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

To move an object from it current position to some other specific position you need to translate by a displacement vector. The displacement vector will be the difference between the desired position and current position.

```
glTranslatef(desired.x-current.x,desired.y-current.y, desired.z-current.z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you brought up the concept of local and global coordinates, then you should also indicate *where* the origin is.

The steps to move the object to a specific XYZ relative to the origin of a specific space is as such:

1. find out the object position in the target space coordinate or;
2. find out the target position in the object space coordinate
3. glTranslate() by the displacement vector in the same coordinate space as per Ken's method

In a professional set up, objects are usually in a hierarchical manner e.g. in an oct-tree; in scene graph; in skeletal animation etc, then you may need to use a recursive function to compute the object position from the object space up its parent space / nodes until you reach the target space where your origin is located.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was able to solve my problem. :)